# Problem with Tkinter and creating a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am quite new with Tkinter and am trying to create a new window using this script while keeping the current window but i am get the error
`_init_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'`. I am not really sure what the reason is but I am assuming that the command function for my button isn't working the way I want it.
The script currently looks something like this:

```
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import *

class Additional(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
#input fields
        Label(master, text="Picture 3 Path:").grid(row=1)

#input fields for tags
#add as needed
        self.e1 = Entry(master)

        self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=150)

        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = self.e1.get()

        self.ttag1 = (first)

class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
#input fields for username and passwords
        Label(master, text="Usernames:").grid(row=1),

        self.e1 = Entry(master)

        self.b1 = Button(master, text = "Add More", bg= 'grey', command= Additional)
        self.b1.grid(row=6, column=2, ipadx=75)

        self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, ipadx=50)

        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = self.e1.get()

        self.tag1 = (first)


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
d = Initial(root)

toor = tk.Tk() 
toor.withdraw()
```

I have tried changing it up but it seems that it's not working right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the `Additional` class through the button command, you are not specifying what the parent root should be, and therefore the class fails to initiate. You can solve this by passing the `master` using a lambda

```py
self.b1 = Button(master, text="Add More", bg='grey', command=lambda: Additional(master))
```